# Function that accepts position-bound parameters as arguments, but also from pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-5.0

I'm attempting to create a logging function that accepts pipeline positionally-bound parameters, and positionally-bound arguments.  However, I keep getting this error with the following code:

```
Function Test
{
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess,DefaultParameterSetName='def')]
Param(
  [Parameter(Position=0,ParameterSetName='def')]
  [String]$Pos1,
  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline,Position=1,ParameterSetName='pip')]
  [String]$InputObject,
  [Parameter(Position=1,ParameterSetName='def')]
  [Parameter(Position=0,ParameterSetName='pip')]
  [String]$State
)
    Process
    {
        Switch ($PScmdlet.ParameterSetName)
        {
            'def' {Write-Host "${State}: $Pos1"}
            'pip' {Write-Host "${State}: $InputObject"}
        }
    }
}

PS C:\> 'this' | Test 'error'

test : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:10
+ 'test' | test 'error'
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (test:String) [Test], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Test
```

I can get the position-bound pipeline calling of the function to work with the following example:

```
Function Test
{
Param(
  [Parameter(Position=1,ValueFromPipeline)]
  [String]$Msg,
  [Parameter(Position=0)]
  [String]$State
)

    Process
    {
        Write-Host "${State}: $Msg"
    }
}

PS C:\> 'this' | Test 'error'
error: this
```

So my question: how can I create a function that will take positionally-bound arguments at command line (`Test 'message' 'status'`) and from the pipeline (`'message' | Test 'status'`) without the need to explicitly call the parameter name (`'message' | Test -State 'status'`)?

Comment: Remove the ParameterSetName from your Pipe, Remove ParameterSetName='pip'

Comment: @ArcSet Doing so causes the position 0 argument to be bound twice, to both `$InputObject` and `$State`, but it did stop throwing errors at me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's replace the `Process { Write-Host "${State}: $Msg" }` block with the following code snippet in the latter script to make more instructive output and get over info from it:

```
Process
{
    ###  Write-Host "${State}: $Msg"
    Write-Host "State=$State`t Msg=$Msg" -NoNewline
    Write-Host "`t`t`t`t$($MyInvocation.Line.trim())" -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
```

Then, check **output** for (almost) all possible combinations of arguments:

```
PS D:\PShell> 
'this' | Test    -State 'error'
'this' | Test           'error'
Test -Msg 'this' -State 'error'
Test -Msg 'this'        'error'
Test      'this' -State 'error'
Test      'this'        'error'

State=error  Msg=this               'this' | Test    -State 'error'
State=error  Msg=this               'this' | Test           'error'
State=error  Msg=this               Test -Msg 'this' -State 'error'
State=error  Msg=this               Test -Msg 'this'        'error'
State=error  Msg=this               Test      'this' -State 'error'
State=this   Msg=error              Test      'this'        'error'

PS D:\PShell>
```

We can see different output for `Test 'this' 'error'` (no pipeline **and** no explicitly named parameters in the line). Therefore, `Test 'error' 'this'` could give "*right*" result.

**Another approach**: let's alter the script output as follows:

```
Function Test
{
Param(
  [Parameter(Position=1,ValueFromPipeline)]
  [String]$Msg,
  [Parameter(Position=0)]
  [String]$State
)
    Process
    {
        #Write-Host "${State}: $Msg"
        $auxLine = $MyInvocation.Line.split( ' ', 
                [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
        if ( $auxLine[0] -eq $MyInvocation.InvocationName -and
                '-Msg'   -notin $auxLine -and
                '-State' -notin $auxLine ) 
        {
            Write-Host "State=$Msg`t Msg=$State" -NoNewline
            Write-Host "`tALTERED`t`t$($MyInvocation.Line.trim())" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        } else {
            Write-Host "State=$State`t Msg=$Msg" -NoNewline
            Write-Host "`t`t`t`t$($MyInvocation.Line.trim())" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
PS D:\PShell> 
'this' | Test    -State 'error'
'this' | Test           'error'
Test -Msg 'this' -State 'error'
Test -Msg 'this'        'error'
Test      'this' -State 'error'
Test      'this'        'error'

State=error  Msg=this               'this' | Test    -State 'error'
State=error  Msg=this               'this' | Test           'error'
State=error  Msg=this               Test -Msg 'this' -State 'error'
State=error  Msg=this               Test -Msg 'this'        'error'
State=error  Msg=this               Test      'this' -State 'error'
State=error  Msg=this   ALTERED     Test      'this'        'error'

PS D:\PShell>
```

Comment: Just to understand this, you're basically checking the non-pipeline input for implicit, position-passed arguments and flipping the output based on that?  Nice use of `$MyInvocation`.

Comment: A little more involved than I was hoping (ParameterSets leave more to be desired), but it definitely works.  Thanks